# Index in List method always returning 0 in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have a problem with the INDEX IN LIST method of App Inventor
which always is returning 0 (zero).

[image]

[image]

Comment: use Do it to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here
[Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: see also ABG's answer here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/zFvvV9DVALg/REy3-JBMAwAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abraham GetzlerPower User

Instead of using the list from csv table block,
use the split at \n block
on your incoming file text.

Since it is just a single column of text delimited
by new line (\n) characters, that will
turn it into a list for you.

by  Abraham Getzler at google forum